# How to delete grants on non-existent procedure?

Tags: mysql, procedure, sql-grant

I've done a

`show grants for daemon@localhost`

command in my database and it shows lines for schemas that where dropped:

> GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `martin_fierro`.`lote_de_tuits` TO 'daemon'@'localhost'

The question is `martin_fierro` schema was dropped long ago so this permission is a nonsense. Is there a way to delete this?

Comment: Can you post the output for `SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE User LIKE '*daemon*'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem issuing a REVOKE EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE xxxx TO yyyy, although the procedure doesn't exist.